# Can an infinite permutatation be decomposed into finite number of infinite cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, infinite-groups

Let $\sigma \in Perm(\mathbb{N})$ the set of permutations on the naturals.  Then can $\sigma$ be written as a finite composition of possibly infinite disjoint cycles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily. Consider the permutation given by

$$\sigma(n)=\begin{cases}
n+1,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
n-1,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;;
\end{cases}$$

it’s $(01)(23)(45)\ldots\;$.

Comment: A nice simple counterexample. +1